# Can I refer to one json object in another object in the same json file?

Tags: json

I'm trying to develop a test automation framework using json to describe data.
 I have a json file which looks like this:

```
{
  "preparation":{
    "configuration":[
      {
        "config1":{
          "src_configfile":"/home/xxx/etc/src_config1.cfg",
          "dest_configfile":"/home/xxx/etc/abc.cfg"
        }
      },
      {
        "config2":{
          "src_configfile":"/home/xxx/etc/src_config2.cfg",
          "dest_configfile":"/home/xxx/etc/xyz.cfg"
        }
      }
    ],
    "executable_info1":[
      {
        "login_info":{
          "hostname":"abc.dw",
          "username":"xyz",
          "password":"*******"
        }
      },
      {
        "command":{
          "folderpath":"/home/xxx/yyy/bin",
          "processname":"sys.exe",
          "parameters":"-d"
        }
      }
    ],
  },
  "execution":[
    {
      "test_case1":{
        "folderpath":"/home/xxx/testscripts",
        "scriptname":"test_case1.py",
       ***???????????Can I access the config1 object here???????????? 
       "config_file"="preparation.configuration[0].config1.dest_configfile"***
      }
    },
    {
      "test_case1":{
        "folderpath":"/home/xxx/testscripts",
        "scriptname":"test_case2.py",
        ***"config_file"="preparation.configuration[1].config2.dest_configfile"***
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to use different config files for different test cases. Can I reference the config1 object of preparation object in the execution???

Comment: As far as I know, not in pure JSON. Now you could make some markup that, on parsing, references the object as you are creating it. So `obj = JSON.parse(json)`, then loop through `obj`'s properties' values and reference other properties if it matches a certain syntax (i.e. `preperation.configuration[0].config1.dest_configfile`).

Comment: Why would you need to reference the config1 object there? I would presume that whatever runtime applicatoin uses this would just need to know which configuration to go with (i.e. just the config1 property name), rather than needing the whole object path referenced.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you can't do that, at least not directly.   For a start, JSON doesn't support circular references.

You might consider using a library such as jsonpath that allows you to reference elements by pattern, but you would tend to need apriori whether a value was an actual value or a reference to some other branch.