# How to append string in json to form a new key, "Key2" : Key1Value +"String"

Tags: json

I have a config.json file and I want to append string to a referenced key in Json. For example

In my case I have one base Url key

```
{APIBase:  "https://apiBase"}
```

I want to reuse this key in the configuration file to form the other keys in json, like instead of doing

```
{APIEndpoint1: "https://apiBase/endPoint1"}
```

I want something like

```
{APIEndpoint1: { "$ref": "#/APIBase" } + AppendString("/endPoint1")}
```

Is there any way to append string in json or any way to achieve this thing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I refer to one json object in another object in the same json file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26023501/can-i-refer-to-one-json-object-in-another-object-in-the-same-json-file)

Comment: @mx0 I know how to reference json key, but want to know how to append string to referenced key.